# Duplicate Component Deisgnator

Tags: altium

I am learning [Altium Designer](https://www.altium.com/) and therefore I've shosen simple audio project. For the sake of [Multichannel Design](https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.1/display/ADES/((Multi-Sheet+and+Multi-Channel+Design))_AD)m I've created simple audio input port, which I am multiplying with `Repeat` command and here is *root sheet*:
[image: Root Sheet]
As you can see, *AUDIO_INPUT* is multiplied *8 times* using `Repeat` command and here is `AUDIO_INPUT` **"zoomed"**:
[image: Audio Input Sheet]
Now, when I try to compile the project, I get following error(s):

```
Class   Document    Source  Message Time    Date    No.

[Error] Sheet4.SchDoc   Compiler    Duplicate Component Designators J2 at 2950mil,5050mil and 2950mil,5050mil   20:05:54    16.05.2018  1
Class   Document    Source  Message Time    Date    No.

[Error] Sheet4.SchDoc   Compiler    Duplicate Component Designators J3 at 2950mil,4050mil and 2950mil,4050mil   20:05:54    16.05.2018  2
```

What did I do wrong? I tried to *reannotate* designators, I get same error.
Nomenclature:

1. **Sheet4.SchDoc** is **root sheet**
2. **Sheet2.SchDoc** is **audio input sheet**

---

I have **deleted** from and **placed** problematic components back to schematic and now the errors(s) are gone. But can someone tell me why?

**ADDENDUM:**
I have forgot to tell my project is under version control and I've commited project to repository, then deleted the contents of `.Annotation` file (I've left the **EMPTY** file itself in project structure) and it compiled ok, but I hardly beleive this is the right way to fix this problem.

Comment: Try adding some connection lines on the top sheet to the ports, or maybe even to some dummy components.  Perhaps the project net-list (or lack of one due to no connections) is confusing the compiler.

Comment: In "Project options", change the "Net identifier scope" to "Hierarchical", and report back.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen it was already set. However, I've noticed all deisgnatiors in multichannel design were same, therefore I've deleted the parts, inserted them back, reannotated the the project and then recompiled it and the errors were gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have two components that have the same value in two different sheets, Example:

```
Sheet2 has   
J2  
J3  

Sheet5 has  
J2  
J3
```

You need to rename the connectors in sheet 5 (or whichever sheet is offending)

```
Sheet2 has    
J2    
J3    

Sheet5 needs to be   
J4  
J5
```

Manually check all of the sub sheets and see if any two designators are the same

If that doesn't work then designate sheet1 and sheet2 first with lower numbered designators (ie J1-J4) and sheet5 to have higher numbered designators (ie J4-J5) so when it repeats it fills in J4-J20